# Crystal Report Join two tables with more than one condition

Tags: join, crystal-reports-xi

my challenge for this day is join a table on crystal without a database-command instead work based on grafic with selection of mysql-tables.

Sorry if i use the wrong translation for the menüs, but i only have a german version.

It means in the database-expert there are selected databasetables instead selecting "add command".
Unfortunately, the report ist created from another person and now i have to alter it.

A simple join is not the problem based on ids. in the profiler i can see

```
inner join table2 on id = id
```

All right. But what i neer is a further condition:

```
on id = id AND (timefrom1 BETWEEN time_to AND time_end or time_to is null)
```

Is there a way to manage this with bumping pixels?

The problem is:
If i change to a sql-command, all fields in the report and the formulars are become canceld. so ist extreamly hard to change the whle report to a sql command.

Hopefully you can help me.

Thanks
Frank

Answer (score 1):

how did you go with this one? I actually haven't defined my tables and links within the Crystal Report file before, so I had to have a play around first to see what you meant.

Rather than include this new filter in your join (which I don't think you can do anyway), have you tried defining this criteria in your Record Selection? Are you aware of how to do this? [This article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=330330&seqNum=2) covers the Select Expert and Record Selection.

This should avoid the problem of losing fields when redefining your data set.

Comment: The Problem is, the Dataset is provided by a 3rd party product and isn't changeable. Thank you for the answer. The article is helpful but didn't solve my problem.